# Float charge heat dissipation of battery

Tags: battery-operated

I have a lead acid battery with specifications shown below.
I wish to calculate the power & energy required to charge the battery from fully discharged.

[image]

Constant current discharge (amperes) at 25 Celsius
1.65V for 15 min=337

Constant power discharge (Watts per cell) at 25 Celsius
1.65V for 15 min=597

Based on the information above, can I know which voltage and amperes should be use to calculate the charge ?heat? dissipation of the battery and what is the formula ?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by 'float discharge heat dissipation' please? I only know of float charging, not sure what float discharging means.

Comment: sorry my bad, what i want to get from you guys is heat generate from battery during float charging.

Comment: sorry about my confusing question.

Comment: Ok, well, it would depend on what voltage you are float charging at, and the state of discharge at the time. From the data sheet info you quoted, they give the temperature compensation factor for the two different use cases of cyclic and standby use. Also, do you want to find the heat produced during a charge after your 15 min discharge, or just the quiescent heat from continuous float charge?

Comment: i get you. hmmm.....let say this battery is float charging at 12V, i face difficulty when i try to calculate the heat produced during a charge after 15 min of discharge.

Comment: Hmm. This is a hard question. Your discharge as stated is 597W per cell for 15 mins, so that works out to about 149 Watt-hours per cell, or 900 Wh in total. This is the amount of energy you are replacing during the charge. But then, the heat depends how quickly this energy is put into the battery during the float charge. If it took 1 hour to recharge to 12V, then the average heating power would be 900 watts during that time. It would be higher at the beginning of charge, and reduce to near zero at the end. Best I can do...

Comment: @SimonTillson No - power dissipated will be electrical energy input - chemical energy absorbed in charging process. Electrical energy will go to I^2R losses and secondary reactions which do not store energy (hopefully minor).

Comment: @T.Ronald You need to put your question more clearly and in adequate detail and to think it through before you post. This is a potentially (pun noted) useful question but you have 3 downvotes and 2 close votes in 8 hours (none from me) and the kneecappers will close your question "until you improve it" if you don't improve it sooner.

Comment: @T.Ronald LA current charge efficiency is high - say 90% + BUT Wattage charge efficiency is lower. Boost charge serves mainly to equalise cells - so current should be low but efficiency may not be good. **BUT** float "charging" is not really "charging" at all - it is maintaining the battery in charged state and only needs to make up self discharge losses so should be very low. For a self discharge of say 10% of capacity in a month (high) you'd need a makeup charge of 200 Ah x 10% / (30 days x 24 hours) ~+ 30 mA and 360 mW for a 12V battery. So "a few Watts" seems a good real world answer.

Comment: Easiest is to measure float current and see.

Comment: @T.Ronald **CRUCIAL** - you need to be sure to use terminology correctly. You say "float charging" which has a very specific meaning **BUT** is that what you really mean? Float charging occurs AFTER the battery is 100% charged. Do you in fact mean "CHARGING" from the discharged to charged state? If so you MUST NOT use the term float charging.

Comment: AND ... :-) - your supplied data text seems to be meaningless :-(. What do the two lines below the image MEAN? (I can guess what they MAY mean but it's by no means obvious). You may be better giving a concise but as long as needed description of what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Yep. I meant to say charge power, not heating power. The heat generated would be a small fraction of the 900W.

Comment: You need to URGENTLY change your question so that it says what you want clearly. Your above comment adds more confusion. Now you have heating power, charge power and float power - ALL different. Write a real question before the downvoters and close voters close the question. You can get it reopened once you tidy it but it makes life harder. **AND** Presentation matters. Use capitals where needed. Use proper sentences. People care about such here and it affects how they respond, like it or not.

Comment: See - now it's on hold :-(. Read the comments. Tidy it up, add the info people have noted is needed. So far it's still unclear exactly what you want to know.

Answer (score 2):

**Charging Mode:**

Lead Acid current charge efficiency is high - say 90% +
BUT Wattage charge efficiency is lower.

Data sheet says max charge current is 60 A. That would be at from about 12V to say 15V.
At that high rate the power would be about 15V x 60A = 900 Watts.
You can charge at substantially lower than that. eg 20A is the nominal 10 hour rate and power would be 12 to 15V x 20A =  240 - 300 Watt range.
Slower again is possible, but very low rates may not fully charge battery. A higher rate may be needed to achieve a topping or boost charge 'at the end' needed to equalise all cells.

Thermal power dissipation would be expected to to in the 10% - 30% range of input power and vary across the cycle. The energy  input to replace output would probably be 110%-130% depending on various factors.

Boost charge serves mainly to equalise cells - so current should be low but efficiency may not be good. BUT  ...

**Float "Charging"**
is not really "charging" at all - it is maintaining the battery in charged state and only needs to make up self discharge losses so should be very low.
For a self discharge of say 10% of capacity in a month (high) you'd need a makeup charge of
200 Ah x 10% / (30 days x 24 hours) ~+ 30 mA
and 360 mW for a 12V battery.

So "a few Watts" seems a good real world answer.

Easiest is to measure float current and see.

---

**Cyclical & Standby use:**

Note that two float voltage ranges are specified by the manufacturer.
14.4 - 14.7V for deepish discharge use. and
13.6 - 13.8V for standby or "float" use.

The former is for where the battery frequently does substantial work and is then recharged after each use. The latter is for when the battery is seldom used to work but "lurks" in full charge mode waiting the time when it will be needed.

---

**Discharge formulae:**

I take the two formulae given to mean as below.
1.65V is "rather low" and should only be used at high rates where IR voltage drops account for quite a lot of the drop and actual cell voltage is higher.
Where did you get those formulae.
The battery will not last 12 years if discharged in that manner frequently.

> Constant current discharge (amperes) at 25 Celcius 1.65V for 15 min=337

Can be discharged from fully charged at a constant 337 amps for 15 mins to an end point voltage of 1.65V per cell.

> Constant power discharge (Watts per cell) at 25 Celcius 1.65V for 15 min=597

Can be discharged from fully charged at a constant 597 Watts for 15 mins to an end point voltage of 1.65V per cell.

**For interest:**

337A x 15/60 h x (2.25 + 1.65)/2 Vavg x 6 cells  = 985 Wh.
597 W x 15/60 h x 6 cells = 895 Wh

For 337A discharge to yield 895 Wh the average voltage per cell = 1.77V (!).

Comment: From the question, it does seem the OP is using the term 'float charging' to mean charging.